# Open tab contents as per dropdown select option selected in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open tab by click of select option. Below are the code of my select option & Tab :

```
<select>
          <option>Select Product</option>
          <option>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
          <option>C</option>
          <option>D</option>
</select>
```

**All** | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D**

A,B,C & D are the category of the product. Inside A, B, C & D Products are there as per there category & **All** holds all the list. I have done these tab functionality using jquery. Now I want to do same as per select option.

Tab HTML :

```
<div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showProduct('', this);" class="active">All</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  id='a' onclick="javascript:showProduct('a', this );" >A</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='b' onclick="javascript:showProduct('b', this);">B</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='c' onclick="javascript:showProduct('c', this);" >C</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='d' onclick="javascript:showProduct('d', this);">D</a>
```

What I need : When I select **A**, tab **A** would be active & there contents shows. How can I do this.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is the HTML for your tabs?

Comment: I hope making a tab active means adding class `.active` to the a having id equivalent to the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="option">
    <option selected value="1">Program 1</option>
    <option value="2">Program 2</option>
    <option value="3">Program 3</option>
    <option value="4">Program 4</option>
</select>
<div class="section" id="1">
    <h2 class="head">Program 1 :
        <h4>Using date function in javascript.</h4>
    </h2>
    <input type="button" onclick="date1()" value="Click to see the Date"/>
    <p id="dateTest"></p>
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="section" id="2">
    <h2 class="head">Program 2 :
        <h4>Changing content on "Button Click"</h4>
    </h2>
    <input type="button" onclick="changecontent()" value="Change"/>
    <p id="changecontent">
        Content before Click.
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//JS for menu view    
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.section').hide();
  $('#1').show();
  $('#option').change(function (){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    if($(this).val()==8)
      init();
  });
});
```

You can put anything in `DIV` as per your requirement. Consider it as dummy data.

Comment: Not working. When I select any option no tab is selected & no content shows. Js not working.

Comment: its a JQuery if you look at it properly. 
You will need to include the following:
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

before you add the script tag for the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showProduct('', this);" class="active tab_class">All</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  id='a' class="tab_class">A</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="tab_class" id='b'>B</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="tab_class" id='c' >C</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="tab_class" id='d'>D</a> 
</div>

    <select class="select">
              <option>Select Product</option>
              <option>A</option>
              <option>B</option>
              <option>C</option>
              <option>D</option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select").change(function(){
         var _curr_tab = $(".select option:selected").html().toLowerCase();
         $(".tab_class").removeClass("active"); // Will remove .active from all "a"
         $("#"+_curr_tab).addClass("active"); // Will add .active to a having id _curr_tab
        showProduct(_curr_tab , document.getElementById(_curr_tab));

     });


    $(".tab_class").click(function(){
      var id=$(this).attr("id");
        showProduct(id, document.getElementById(id));
    });

});

function showProduct(a,b)
{
$(".tab_class").removeClass("active");
$("#"+a).addClass("active");
}
```

CSS

```
.active{font-size:30px;}
```

Link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/upjmcnbL/

I hope now it solves your problem... :)

Comment: Tabs are working fine. Same thing I want in dropdown. When I select **B** then **B** is active & through Jquery content of category **B** shows.

Comment: @Shaan why are you passing `this` in `showProduct()` function call?

Comment: Due to another functionality. The code which you are posted is not working. No need to add #id in options.

Comment: No its not working in my site. When I select any option nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share you website link over here or its source code? Is it working on the jsFiddle?